# TERMIOS: What is the OFILL flag in c_oflag used for?

Tags: linux, terminal, termios

**Question 1: What is the `OFILL` flag in `termios_p->c_oflag` is used for.**

Here is what the documentation says:

> Send fill characters for a delay, rather than using a timed delay.

To play around with this, I have created this little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char c;
    int res;
    struct termios termios_old, termios_new;

    res = tcgetattr(0, &termios_old);
    assert(res == 0);
    termios_new = termios_old;

    // Setup the terminal in raw mode
    termios_new.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP |
                             INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    termios_new.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    termios_new.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    termios_new.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    termios_new.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // Add the flag I'm trying to understand
    termios_new.c_oflag |= OFILL;  // What is this flag used for?


    res = tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &termios_new);
    assert(res == 0);

    while (1) {
        read(0, &c, 1);
        printf("0x%x %d\r\n", (int)c, (int)c);

        if (c == 'q')
            break;
    }

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &termios_old);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program I see no differences if the flag is set, or not set... I was hoping that this flag somehow could make it easier to detect if the `ESC` key was pressed.

In the program above I see the exactly same output if I press the `Left-Arrow-key` and if I press the sequence: `ESC` `[` `D`.

**Question 2: How should I detect if the user pressed the `ESC` button and how should I detect if the user pressed the `Left-arrow-button**

As this is an exercise in learning how the terminal IO system is working, then I do not want to use any libraries.

Comment: I think you may be confusing termios' delays with your terminal adding a delay to do character escaping.

Answer (score 0):

The OFILL flag is used pretty much like the documentation you've posted says - instead of waiting a certain timed delay, send some fill bytes. This is sometimes done on high speed uarts because the timed delay is really long compared to the time needed to send two fill bytes, and both sides are capable of operating near full speed.

For your example, if stdin has no reason to send you a delay, it probably won't, so that would explain your program not seeing any fill bytes. Since this is a transmitter-side option, I'm not sure you can cause stdin to emit fill-bytes.

I would also look at NLDLY/NL0/NL1, which can trigger fill bytes to be sent, but I'm not sure how those would affect stdin/stdout.

Comment: When I press the `ECS` key I see a delay (~1 sec) before the application receive any input.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior

Comment: No, I have not found that question but it looks interesting, thanks. I'm wandering waht tmux does when setting `escape-time 0`